How to delete old commits to save space?
I am not into these things and i don't know coding but i work on UNREAL ENGINE 5.1 and my team is using source control connected to git repository (we just followed some tutorials) and we have more than 100 commits and we are running out of space and we cant afford more data packs so is there any way to delete old commits?
i tried searching i found some articles but i couldn't understand
Remove old git commits
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/deleted-files-wont-commit-deleted-status-to-git-repository/316115

Uh. Problem is probably, that you store large binary files in git. Git Is bad at that. Don't do that. Google for instructions on how to remove large binary files from a git repository.

Note that you kinda can't remove anything from git. When "remove" things from git commit history, you basically create a new got repository with different commit history.

Yes, you can but you could potentially disrupt the work of your team. First make sure you have a backup of your repo.
Here is how you can do it:
1. Identify commits you need to delete:
You can use the git log command to view the commit history. If you're looking to delete commits older than a certain date, you can use the --since option:
  git log --until="2024-03-03"

Adjust the date as needed.The Format is YYYY-MM-DD
2. Create a New Branch Without the Commits:
Once you've identified the commits you want to delete, you can create a new branch that starts from the commit just before the ones you want to remove. For example, if you want to delete commits from commit_id onwards, you can do:
 git checkout -b new_branch commit_id^

This command creates a new branch named new_branch that starts from the commit just before commit_id
3. Force Push the New Branch
After creating the new branch, you need to force push it to the remote repository. This will overwrite the history on the remote repository with the new branch's history so communicate with your team before doing this step to avoid disrupting their work.:
 git push origin new_branch:main --force

This command force pushes new_branch to the main branch on the remote repository. Replace main with the name of your main branch if it's different
5. Rebase Local Branches
Your team members will need to rebase their local branches onto the new history
 git fetch origin
 git rebase origin/main

Replace main with the name of your main branch if it's different.
6. Clean Up
After your team has successfully rebased their branches, you can delete the old branch from the remote repository:
 git push origin --delete old_branch

Replace old_branch with the name of the branch you want to delete.
WARNING!

Backup: Always make a backup of your repository before performing
operations that rewrite history.
Communication: Communicate with your team about the changes you're
making. Ensure everyone is aware of the new history and knows how to
rebase their local branches.
Risks: Be aware of the risks involved in rewriting history. It can
lead to lost work if not done carefully.

My Suggested Optimal Solution:
Since you are using Unreal Engine, you most certainly have a lot of very large files. Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) can be a solution to manage large files in your Git repository without bloating the repository size. Git LFS replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.
Here's how you can set up and use Git LFS for your project:
1. Install Git LFS
You can download it from the official website here or install it using a package manager. For example, on macOS, you can use Homebrew:
 brew install git-lfs

Homebrew Formulae here
On Windows, you can download the installer from the Git LFS website
2.Set Up Git LFS for Your Repository
Navigate to your repository's directory in the terminal and run the following command to initialize Git LFS:
 git lfs install

3. Track Large Files
Specify which files should be handled by Git LFS. This is done by creating or modifying the .gitattributes file in your repository. For example, to track all .psd files, you would add the following line to .gitattributes:
 *.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

You can track multiple file types by adding more lines to the .gitattributes file.
4. Add, Commit, and Push Your Changes
After setting up Git LFS and specifying which files to track, you can add, commit, and push your changes as usual. Git LFS will automatically handle the large files.
 git add .
 git commit -m "Add large files"
 git push origin main

Replace main with the name of your branch if it's different.
5. Manage Large Files
To manage your large files using Git LFS commands. For example, to list all LFS files in your repository, you can use:
 git lfs ls-files

And to remove a file from LFS tracking, you can use:
 git lfs untrack "*.psd"

Git LFS documentation can be found here
